# Bash: Difference between $(cat) and "$a"

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Is there any difference between capturing arguments passed to a script using `$(cat)` and `$@`?

For example is this any different

```
my_data=$(cat)
echo "$my_data" | "$my_script"
```

than executing

```
"$my_script" "$@"
```

I ask this because I found a case where `$(cat)` wasn't catenating it's stdin to stdout like it's supposed to when running git hooks.  Hence it wasn't capturing args, however, `$@` had no problem.

Comment: `cat` is an external program and produces an unnecessary child process.  If you wish to read stdin then used the shell builtin `read`.   `$@`` are the command-line arguments and are unconnected to stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely pointless:

```
my_data=$(cat)
echo "$my_data" | "$my_script"
```

If `$my_script` reads standard input, then this will be roughly equivalent:

```
"$my_script"
```

That's right, no `cat`, no `echo`. If the first example worked, this should work too, except for the one tiny difference that the first version also adds an extra newline because of the `echo`.

Your question seems to be about different ways of passing input to programs. One way is passing on standard input. For example:

```
cat data.txt | prog
prog < data.txt
```

In these examples, `prog` can read the content of `data.txt` from `stdin`. If there are multiple distinct values, `prog` must parse the input appropriately to separate the values.

Another way to pass input to programs is via command line arguments, for example:

```
prog a "b c"
```

In this example the shell will pass two values to the program, and the program can access those values directly without any parsing.

Passing by standard input had the advantages that you can pass large data verbatim. Passing by command line arguments has the advantage that you can pass distinct values without having to parse them. It has the disadvantage that the command line has a length limit, and also that you have to be careful to escape values that might be interpreted by the shell.

You can use whichever method is more suitable to your task. You can also use both at the same time, if that makes sense for your program.